# Does Java's for-each call an embedded method (that returns the collection) for every iteration?

Tags: java, foreach

If there is a method call `MyClass.returnArray()` and I iterate over the array using the for-each construct (also called the "enhanced for" loop):

```
for (ArrayElement e : MyClass.returnArray()) {
   //do something
}
```

will then the `returnArray()` method be called for every iteration?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

No, it won't. The result of the first call will be stored in the compiled code in a temporary variable.

From [Effective Java 2nd. Ed.](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/effective/), Item 46:

> Note that there is no performance penalty for using
>   the for-each loop, even for arrays. In fact, it may offer a slight performance advantage
>   over an ordinary for loop in some circumstances, as it computes the limit of
>   the array index only once.

Comment: If you wonder about the downvote, I agree with the conclusion, but I don't think that the part you quoted does explain the why particularly well. It talks mainly about the array index, which is not in question and fails to explain - let alone prove - that the `returnArray` method in the "expression" is called only once.

Answer (score 13):

From the [java language spec](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/statements.html#14.14.2):

```
EnhancedForStatement:
    for ( VariableModifiersopt Type Identifier: Expression) Statement
```

and later on:

```
T[] a = Expression;
L1: L2: ... Lm:
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        VariableModifiersopt Type Identifier = a[i];
        Statement
}
```

This is (in pseudo code) the equivalent of the advanced for loop for arrays. And it is made clear, that the *Expression* is evaluated once and the resulting array is assigned to `T[] a`.

So it's perfectly safe to use even complex expressions in the advanced for loop statement.

Answer (score 5):

No.

The for loop is just syntactic sugar.  It behaves [differently](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17476_01/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) depending on whether or not it is applied to an Array argument or an object implementing the Iterable interface.

For Iterable objects, the loop expands to something like this:

```
Iterator<ArrayElement> iter = iterableObject.iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
   ArrayElement e = iter.next();
   // do smth
}
```

What your example code is actually doing is something like this:

```
Object[] temp = Method.returnArray();
for ( int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++ ) {
  ArrayElement e = (ArrayElement) temp[i];
  // do smth
}
```

Comment: This is perfectly true for all subclasses of `Iterable` but the advanced for loop can be used with arrays too, and I guess, that was the point of the question. It's still 'syntactical sugar' but a bit different.

Answer (score 2):

No, it will be called once. It's not like the termination condition of a standard for loop, which gets evaluated on every iteration.