# Java foreach performance

Tags: java, foreach

I've using the `"foreach"` loop in my `Java` applications for a long time. Recently I started wondering if there is any significative difference in performance (or even in the result) between:

```
Collection<String> collection = someMethod();
for(String element : collection) { ... }
```

and:

```
for(String element : someMethod()) { ... }
```

What if instead of a `Collection` it is a `List`, a `Map`, a `Set` or an `array`?

Comment: Why would you suspect a performance difference?

Comment: How did you find the difference in performance?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a performance difference between a for loop and a for-each loop?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/256859/is-there-a-performance-difference-between-a-for-loop-and-a-for-each-loop)

Comment: @Philipp I've read the first option is the "best practice" and I wanted to know if there is any performance reason for that

Comment: @JaviFernández there is no performance difference. It's more about not having to know the returned collection type, if anything.

Comment: I'd prefer the former. If you are wondering if someMethod() is called multiple times (it shouldn't be), put a debug statement in there.

Comment: @PeterLawrey not the same question

Comment: Thank you very much. So it's more about style than performance, isn't it?

Comment: @JaviFernández Basically the same answer. The code and result is much the same between the two alternatives.

Comment: I think he was being afraid that someMethod() will be called multiple times(more exactly: for each iteration) , resulting into a tiny-to-huge performance difference, depending on what `someMethod()` is doing. I think it is a duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3298202/does-advanced-for-each-loop-in-java-call-method-that-returns-an-array-to-iterate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a semantic difference, you won't see any real performance change in your code as a result of assigning a method return value to a local variable. Lists, Sets, Map entry sets, arrays are all iterable in the for-each loop, so they are all fine and result in you not having to know the return collection type.

Answer (score 3):

The difference between both codes can be seen in their generated bytecodes.

The first one has extra two instructions over the second one; it stores the return value of `someMethod()` on the local stack and then loads it again for accessing it's iterator.

However the second one immediately uses the `Iterator` without storing the return value of `someMethod()` on the local stack.

Below code shows the elimination of `3:` and `4:` instructions.

**First:**

```
Collection<String> collection = someMethod();
for(String element : collection) { ... }

     0: invokestatic  #3                  // Call someMethod()
     3: astore_1                          // Store the result as first item on local stack
     4: aload_1                           // Load the Collection again into operand stack
     5: invokeinterface #4,  1            // Get Iterator (of Collection) - InterfaceMethod java/util/Collection.iterator:()Ljava/util/Iterator;
    10: astore_2                          // Store Iterator on local stack #2
    11: aload_2                           // LOOP STARTS - Load iterator
    12: invokeinterface #5,  1            // InterfaceMethod java/util/Iterator.hasNext:()Z
    17: ifeq          33
    20: aload_2       
    21: invokeinterface #6,  1            // InterfaceMethod java/util/Iterator.next:()Ljava/lang/Object;
    26: checkcast     #7                  // class java/lang/String
    29: astore_3      
    30: goto          11                  // LOOP ENDS
    33: return
```

**Second**

```
for(String element : someMethod()) { ... }

     0: invokestatic  #3                  // Call someMethod() 
     3: invokeinterface #4,  1            // Get Iterator (of Collection) - Interface Method java/util/Collection.iterator:()Ljava/util/Iterator;/
     8: astore_1                          // Store Iterator on local stack #2  
     9: aload_1                           // LOOP STARTS - Load iterator
    10: invokeinterface #5,  1            // InterfaceMethod java/util/Iterator.hasNext:()Z
    15: ifeq          31
    18: aload_1       
    19: invokeinterface #6,  1            // InterfaceMethod java/util/Iterator.next:()Ljava/lang/Object;
    24: checkcast     #7                  // class java/lang/String
    27: astore_2      
    28: goto          9                   // LOOP ENDS
    31: return
```

BTW, I don't think that they will have a big difference in terms of performance since both have 9 instructions inside the loop.

Answer (score 2):

There is no visible performance difference between the two. The first way is more elegant and readable than the second one. But from performance point of view its not a deterrent. Both produce identical bytecode for the 'inside the loop' part.

Answer (score 1):

For compatibility you shall use the second and if you know the result is never `null`.

The first shall not be used if you dont need the `collection` anymore.

I prefer a third suggestion:

```
Collection<String> collection = someMethod();
if (collection != null) {
    for(String element : collection) { ... }
}
```

Regards.

Comment: I usually prefer to return an empty collection if `someMethod()` is written by me and not part of some 3rd party library, just to avoid these annoying checkings against null.

Comment: I really like you to be my collegue. Can i ask you something? how do you think about `assert collection != null;`?

Comment: I think it is a really bad idea to use assertion in these situations(before iterating over a collection) because I would not like my program to terminate if the collection is null. IMHO assertions have their place in testing , not in production code,  but again: this is only my humble opinion .